# Kafka OffsetOutOfRangeException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am streaming loads of data through kafka. And then I have spark streaming which is consuming these messages. Basically down the line, spark streaming throws this error:

```
kafka.common.OffsetOutOfRangeException
```

Now I am aware what this error means. So I changed the retention policy to 5 days. However I still encountered the same issue. Then I listed all the messages for a topic using --from-beginning in kafka. Surely enough, ton of messages from the beginning of the kafka streaming part were not present and since spark streaming is a little behind the kafka streaming part, spark streaming tries to consume messages that have been deleted by kafka. However I thought changing the retention policy would take care of this:

```
--add-config retention.ms=....
```

What I suspect is happening that kafka is deleting messages from the topic to free up space (because we are streaming tons of data) for the new messages. Is there a property which I can configure that specifies how much bytes of data kafka can store before deleting the prior messages?

Comment: Did you use old consumer or new consumer? And also check `auto.offset.reset`

Comment: I just created a spark direct stream

Comment: did my answer answered your question?

Comment: yes it did, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the maximum size of the topic when u create the topic using the topic configuration property `retention.bytes` via console like:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --topic my-topic --partitions 1  --replication-factor 1 --config retention.bytes=10485760 --config
```

or u can use global broker configuration property `log.retention.bytes` to set the maximum size for all topics.

what is important to know is that `log.retention.bytes` doesn't enforce a hard limit on a topic size, but it just signal to Kafka when to start deleting the oldest messages

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this problem is to specify in the configuration the spark parameter :

```
spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition
```